# Kendo UI MVVM : Change increment step of number field in grid

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the increment value of the number "spinner" in a Kendo UI grid field? I know it can be done in a stand-along numbericTextBox but I haven't been able to find any information about values inside a grid.

Ideally I'd like it so when I increment or decrement using the up and down arrows, it does so by .5 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but for future reference, you can use the `editor` field for manipulating your numeric textbox.

```
{ 'field': 'count', title: 'Count', editor: numericEditor }
```

In your js file, you initialize the numeric textbox

```
function numericEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input type="number" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoNumericTextBox({
            min: 1,
            step: .5,
        });
}
```

Here's a [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/IkAKOd/4) for demo